# Error al mostrar resultados de consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Realizo una consulta para que me muestre los días disponibles que tiene el usuario para tomar vacaciones, hago la consulta directa en consola de SQL y me arroja el resultado correcto en este caso el usuario tiene 3 días disponibles pero en el contador solo me muestra 1 día disponible.

Por lo que intuyo que mi consulta es correcta pero al mostrarla algo esta pasando, no me arroja como tal ningún error pero es incorrecto el resultado.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Saludos.

**Consulta para saber que dias tiene disponible el usuario que esta logueado.**

```html
<?php


 $Tickets = mysqli_query(
  $con,
  "
      SELECT
   u_dias_disponibles
   FROM v_vacaciones_completo
  
  WHERE
   user_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['user_id']) . "'
  "


?>
```

**Muestra el resultado de la consulta**

```html
                                                                                                  
      <div class="animated flipInY col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
       <div class="tile-stats">
       <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
       <div class="count"><?php echo mysqli_num_rows($Tickets) ?></div>
     <h3>Saldo de Vacaciones</h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

[image: En la imagen es donde muestra el resultado de la consulta, en este caso tiene que ser 3 ya que el usuario logueado tiene 3 días disponibles pero siempre muestra 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hace mysqli_num_rows es mostrarte el número de filas, debes obtener el valor de la columna:

```
<?php 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($Tickets); 
?>

<div class="animated flipInY col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
       <div class="tile-stats">
       <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
       <div class="count"><?php echo $row['u_dias_disponibles']; ?></div>
     <h3>Saldo de Vacaciones</h3>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Solamente subrayar que `mysqli_fetch_array` no es la mejor opción para este caso, porque te arroja dos resultados, uno numérico y uno asociativo. Es mejor usar [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que es más específico, arrojando un solo resultado, el asociativo. También en cuanto a la seguridad, es mejor usar consultas preparadas que funciones de escape.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando la función `mysqli_num_rows` que lo que hace es contar la cantidad de filas que trae la consulta.

Deberías realizar lo siguiente para traer el resultado de la consulta:

```php
$row= $Tickets->fetch_assoc();
$row['u_dias_disponibles'];
```